# How do I run a C++ binary on OpenShift via PHP?

Tags: php, c++, openshift

I SSH'd into my OpenShift application and compiled the C++ file using `gcc` and then downloaded it to my computer (for backup). I added it to git repo and pushed it.

How do I execute it in the current directory? I have tried changing permissions to 777 using `chmod`. I've tried `exec()`, `shell_exec()`, `passthru()`, `system()` in PHP with no luck. None of them gives me the output of the program.

Commands I used

Compiling C++: `gcc code.cpp -o code.out`
Inside `run.php`: `chmod 777 code.out && ./code.out input-file` (also tried `chmod("code.out", 777);`)

`input-file` is also pushed together with the `code.out` in same directory.

After a bit of testing, I found that it returns code `126` which is `Permission problem or command is not an executable`, but the permissions is 777 and it is in fact an executable.

Am I missing something?

(I'm sorry, but I don't have any experience with this)

Comment: `ls -l` show it to be executable? And the input file permission?

Comment: Gimme a second, I'll SSH into the server and check it. Edit: Yes, it does. It does show "x" in permissions.

Comment: Both the files? Weird. Your executable depend on any non standard lib?

Comment: Are you sure your executable outputs to stdout?

Comment: Yes, both the files. And nope, no non-standard lib, uses only stdio, stdlib and memory. It does compile and I can execute it via SSH correctly.

Comment: What happens if you change the last bit to be this: `chmod 777 code.out && ./code.out ./input-file` -- This assumes all 3 files are next to each other

Comment: @DanielM I'm using printf for output. I think that shouldn't matter for exit code 126, correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: Gimme a second, I'll try that @DanielM.

Comment: Nope, does not work. Same 126 exit code. @DanielM

Comment: What about giving the full path to each file?

Comment: Also, using `is_file()`, should tell you if PHP can see the files where you expect them to be.

Comment: How do I find the full path of the file on OpenShift? It's pretty sandboxed environment. 

Also, the `./input-file` shouldn't have worked anyways. Because, that argument is just a file name and I open it using `fopen` inside C++.
I've tried `passthru("ls")`, and it does give me the list of files in current directory including the executable and the input file.

Comment: @AkshatMittal what about `pwd` if you're in the same directory as that file?

Comment: As it is, `code.out` would have to be in the same directory as `run.php`. If it isn't you need to make the path relative to `run.php` or make it absolute. Note: it's almost certainly a bad idea having it in a folder that is being server by your web server. :)

Comment: All the three files, `run.php`, `code.out` and `input-file` are in the same directory. I'm still trying what @MarcoA. said.

Comment: Sorry, I was elaborating on @MarcoA.'s comment. If they're in the same directory, it shouldn't make a difference `pwd` just tells you the current working directory.

Comment: Tried specifying the full path, still same result. Just confirm me once, this permission is alright for `code.out` right? `-r----x--t.`

Comment: Try `-rwxrwxrwx`. See if it can run

Comment: @frz3993, I don't know why but I am sure I was using 777 permission before also, but it worked now. Still, add an answer and I'll mark it correct. :)

Comment: Oh wait, I got it. The difference was 777 vs 0777. Stupid me. Anyways, thanks everyone. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the permission of the file so all can execute.

```
chmod a+rwx file
```

I prefer to use this instead of using `0777`. That depends on your preference though.

Comment: Notice that this is **not** always the best solution, in this particular instance it might work since the app is sandboxed in a protected environment (and I suppose there aren't other users using it in the system). Attention should be paid if there are other user groups or accesses.

Comment: I'm assuming the same.

Comment: I'm going to try giving it executable permission into different groups and check which of them works.